# Is there a term or phrase for a list of residents displayed at the door in a shared home?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, american-english

I currently live in a rented home with roommates not related to me. All residents of the house are listed on a laminated paper dispayed by the house's mail slot. In our experience, the United States Postal Service will not deliver mail (especially packages) to our address unless the receiver's name is present on this list. Is there a term or specific phrase for this list of current residents displayed to the postal carrier?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**directory**

> The rugged stainless steel faceplate has a printed **name directory**
>   housed in a waterproof, scratch-resistant lens. Each button is beside
>   the *tenant's* name in the apartment directory.

https://www.vikingelectronics.com/products/k-1200/

> This **name directory** is designed specifically to *complement* secure
>   building door entry systems and is constructed for both weather and
>   vandal resistance.

https://www.vikingelectronics.com/products/d10/

Edit to add: the USPS guidance refers to **directory**:

> 632.626 **Directories**
>
> ***Guidelines*** for Postal Service apartment house **directories** are as follows:
>
> a. For all apartment houses with 15 or more
>   receptacles, maintain a complete **directory** of all persons
>   receiving mail. If an apartment house is divided into units, each with
>   separate entrances and 15 or more receptacles, each unit should have a
>   separate directory. In addition, if mail is not generally addressed to
>   specific units, a directory must be kept at the main unit of the
>   building listing all persons receiving mail in the various units.
>
> Directories must be alphabetical by surname and must be maintained and
>   kept up-to-date. ...
>
> c. The directory must be legible, enclosed in a
>   suitable protective frame, and attached to the wall immediately above
>   or to the side of the mail receptacles where it can easily be read.

https://about.usps.com/what-we-are-doing/current-initiatives/delivery-growth-management/section-632.pdf